# Empty cells have a fixed width of 0?

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I have a table with 5 columns, 2 of which have a set width, the other three don't. Different browsers interpret this inconsistently.

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WACLY/) in different browsers to see what I mean.

Firefox and IE9 render it the way I'd think correct: all cells have uniform width of 20% (two have a set width of 20% each, and the remaining 60% is divided between the remaining three cells).

Chrome, Opera, IE7 and IE8 force the empty cells without a set width to have zero width, which in turn forces the other two cells to stretch to 50% width each. Putting content into one of the three empty cells makes them take all available width (60% in case one cell has content, 30% if two, etc.). Likewise, removing the content off one of the two cells that have a set width results in a forced 0 width.

Which browsers got it right and which ones are doing it wrong?

Also, I perused the W3C spec regarding tables, but only found the [description of the `empty-cells` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#empty-cells), which is supposed to control the rendering of empty cells with borders/background, but this does not affect the cells' width. I thought the [`table-layout` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout) might do the trick, but while setting `table-layout:fixed` in Chrome does make all the columns appear, there is no way (or at least I don't see one) to do the opposite in Firefox. If you could elaborate on this and/or point me to the correct section of the W3C spec that covers this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Is there a problem with using just `table td { width: 20%; }`?

Comment: I found an odd behaviour and would like to know more about its causes. I never said I had a problem with anything :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises as the W3C haven't seemed to cover it yet, they haven't suggested any "right" way of dealing with this situation. The browsers have the liberty to interpret it the way they wish, in my opinion is the way IE9 and Firefox do it.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO all the browsers are displaying things RIGHT. As a developer we should understand that what we expect from the empty cells. It is always better to define width or add some spaces even if your cell is going to be empty to achieve consistent display across all browsers.

Comment: As with the answer by Stefan, you're trying to provide me with a solution, which is not what I'm asking for. I know how to avoid the problem. I want to know its *cause* and possible compliance with W3C standards.

Comment: this link might help: http://www.qwconsulting.com/blog/gecko-vs-trident-browser-issues.html

Comment: And where exactly do they cover the subject of my question? This is a text for non tech-savvy people that can be summed up in one sentence: "different layout engines interpret CSS differently". That's kind of obvious, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

put `&nbsp;` inside the "empty" `<td>`

Comment: I'm not asking for a solution, as it's easy to find one. I'm asking for an explanation of the misbehaviour and a pointer to the "default" behaviour by W3C.

Comment: if i'm not mistaking ... is a small optimization to save rendering invisible/useless items ... i believed in Firefox (older versions) hidden images (with css) or overlayed with divs where not loaded in page.

Comment: Determining whether something is "useless" is not exactly up to the browser. As for "invisible" - the elements in question aren't invisible in Firefox. I'm asking about what W3C says about it: whether the empty cells should or should not be rendered and why the browsers follow different conventions: lack of an official position on the subject (freedom of spec interpretation) or incomplete implementation of the set standards.